# URL doesn't get an anchor after click

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

On the page http://example.com/page.html I have

```
<a href="#section-1">to section 1</a>
...
<section id="section-1">...</section-1>
```

After clicking on the link the page moves to the correct place, where section-1 begins, but the URL doesn't become http://example.com/page.html#section-1

What prevents the URL from getting the anchor? Can I do something to let the URL become anchor after click?

**Edit**: as often, immediately after I post a question at SO I find a cause of misbehavior. It was a javascript, which prevented the addinf of anchor to the URL.

Comment: More information/code is needed. Is your page online somewhere that it can be tested? Go to https://brave.com/privacy-updates/20-grab-bag-ios/ and select one of the links on the left, beneath Table of Contents. Does this page show the expected anchor behavior? If not, which browser are you using? Any extensions that may be interrupting the expected behavior?

Comment: @Sampson: on the page you linked I experience correct behavior - anchor is in the URL after clicking. But If i run my page, which is local, in same browsers, latest Chrome and Edge, the anchor isn't there.

Comment: Happy to hear that you found the issue; presumably something like `e.preventDefault()` on some click-handler?